# NeuralTalk2 Error

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I am getting the following output on trying to run neuraltalk2

```
parag@parag:~/MyHome/neuraltalk2/neuraltalk2-master$ th eval.lua -model /home/parag/MyHome/neuraltalk2/ -image_folder /home/parag/MyHome/neuraltalk2/images/ -num_images -1 -gpuid -1
/home/parag/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/parag/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:199: read error: read 0 blocks instead of 1 at /home/parag/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/THDiskFile.c:314
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'readInt'
/home/parag/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:199: in function 'readObject'
/home/parag/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:325: in function 'load'
eval.lua:69: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
...arag/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00405d70
```

parag@parag:~/MyHome/neuraltalk2/neuraltalk2-master$

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

My command was incomplete. The full path of model including the model name is to be given in the command as follows:

```
$ th eval.lua -model /home/parag/MyHome/neuraltalk2/model_id1-501-1448236541.t7_cpu.t7 -image_folder /home/parag/MyHome/neuraltalk2/images/ -num_images -1 -gpuid -1
```

This solved the issue for me!